# Do mutations come in pairs?

Tags: bioinformatics, dna-helix

As DNA is organized in a double-helix, a change in one strand must be accompanied by a corresponding change in the other strand. Let's say an original sequence CATCAT mutates into CATGAT. The other strand must change from GTAGTA to GTACTA - or, more precisely, as the other strand is read in the opposite direction, from ATGATG to ATCATG, possibly in a completely different gene. Has the effect of this pairing of mutations been explored mathematically?

Comment: Welcome to Biology! What exactly do you mean with *Has the effect [...] been explored **mathematically**?* Mathematically implies you wish a theoretical analysis of the occurrence of mutated base pairs? Or do you want to know if indeed mutations are characterized by changed base pairs?

Comment: If a mutation has to be accompanied by a second mutation, only loosely related (by an accident of being on a strand exactly opposite the first mutation), it should affect a frequency of survival, or of a beneficial change. We should not consider a single mutation in isolation.

Comment: Note that DNA repair mechanisms catch odd bases. A mutation is per definition a change in base pair. Further, only 1 strand serves a basis for transcription. The other one does not. This question is quite unclear to me and I vote for closure until refined.

Comment: If a mutation occurs in one strand and is missed by repair mechanisms, it will be copied to the new complementary strand during replication. You'll end up with one double helix with the mutation and one without. That said, I also don't understand your question.

Comment: @AliceD This is a technicality, but rarely you will find two genes that overlap on complementary strands and so both strands serve as a transcription template at that locus.

Comment: @canadianer - we might have to take this to chat, but I always thought the complementary DNA strand was the template and the other coding strand just acts as a backbone. So the coding DNA strand carries the code, but does not act as the template during mRNA transcription. If that makes sense...

Comment: @AliceD You're absolutely correct, I was just referring to cases of overlapping genes, like [this](http://www.genetics.org/content/152/2/743.abstract?ijkey=26609109343ff0830018f5f64003de18215732f7&keytype2=tf_ipsecsha). So both strands at that locus act as a template for transcription. One of my previous professors claimed that essentially every part of the genome is transcribed at some point, which seems to be at least partially validated by papers like [this](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12640466/).

Comment: While the question of mathematics makes no sense. The intention of the question is clear. What would happen if the DNA repair like nucleotide excision repair has failed to repair the DNA? I think the answer is that the mutated base will be replicated among with its new base-pair.